# Почему Firefox Mozilla не берет изображения из кэша при подстановке через javascript?

Tags: javascript, браузер, firefox

При наведении курсора на элемент страницы, через javascript, подставляется фоновое изображение. Подстановка происходит именно разных изображений, для возможности эффекта плавной их смены (transition: background 0.3s linear). Для Firefox пробовал и с префиксом, но в последней версии (67.0.4) это CSS свойство и так должно поддерживаться.

Вот как делаю в JS:

`htmlElement.style = "background-image: url('/img/mainpage/img01.png') center top no-repeat";`

Суть в том, что браузеры Хром, Опера, Эйдж после сохранения изображений в кэш, в дальнейшем берут их из него, а вот Firefox при каждой подстановке, обращается на сервер за изображениями. Из-за этого происходит подергивание изображений при смене. Почему Firefox их не берет из кэша, если он их туда сохраняет?

Возможно, это происходит именно из-за того, что они подставляются через javascript. Тогда подскажите в какую сторону двигаться для решения этой проблемы.

Comment: как вариант - использовать serviceworker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуй подгрузить картинки через теги `<link rel="preload" as="image" href="адресс картинки">` может поможет. А вообще с точки зрения производительности эффективнее картинки хранить в теге picture а не брать из background